# Is there a way to have push notifications for different groups

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, group-by, push-notification

I want to be able to send push notifications in my app. But i would like to be able to send them to certain categories like country

any way to do this if there is 25-30 different categories

also a way for somebody to pick a category and then get push notifications for that category

Answer (score 1):

I handle sending push notifications myself, the backend receives push keys from the mobile apps after login, this way I can decide which user I want to send push notifications... This way you can decide how to implement subscription and push mechanism yourself, and check if a user has a topic enabled and is in the specified country.

Anyway: more info will get you better responses: ios? android? external push notification service? used frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Firebase Topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging)?

> Based on the publish/subscribe model, FCM topic messaging allows you to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic. You compose topic messages as needed, and FCM handles routing and delivering the message reliably to the right devices.
>
> For example, users of a local tide forecasting app could opt in to a
>   "tidal currents alerts" topic and receive notifications of optimal
>   saltwater fishing conditions in specified areas. Users of a sports app
>   could subscribe to automatic updates in live game scores for their
>   favorite teams.

You could simply subscribe/unsubscribe users from the relevant country topic.